# Javascript If statement not getting false when it should be

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom

Trying to make a calculator for a triangle to see if the given sides can form one and if it's a right angle one. I create more buttons for more options to calculate, but I'm having issues with my If statement. When the result should be false it stays true, I'm using the && operator since as I understand it means both conditions on either side of it have to be true for it to proceed and I shouldn't be having an issue with nested if statements.

If I do 10 for length 1 and then 1 for lengths 2 and 3, it should pass the first part fine since they're both true, but the nested if statement should come back false since neither length 2 or 3 add up past length 1, but it returns to me as true continues to give me the "can form triangle" text I setup.

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var testButton = document.getElementById("tests");
    testButton.onclick = addTests;
};

function addTests() {
    var test1 = document.createElement("button");
    test1.innerHTML = "(1) Test whether these three sides can form a triangle";
    document.body.appendChild(test1);
    test1.onclick = function() {
        var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
        var length1 = document.getElementById("length a");
        var length2 = document.getElementById("length b");
        var length3 = document.getElementById("length c");
        
        if (length1 + length2 > length3 && length1 + length3 > length2)
        {
                if (length2 + length3 > length1)
                {
                    result = "These three sides can form a triangle!";
                    answer.innerHTML = result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "These three sides cannot form a triangle!";
                    answer.innerHTML = result;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            result = "These three sides cannot form a triangle!";
            answer.innerHTML = result;
        }

    };
```

Comment: `length1`, `length2` and `length3` are HTML elements, not numbers.

Comment: Hi! I've only made a quick look to your code, and I realized that you are NOT comparing the values of the TextBoxes (or whatever element you are assigning to length1, etc). What you are doing is saving the REFERENCES to the elements with the `document.getElementById()` lines. Once you have the reference to the element, you should get the VALUE of the referenced element. For example, TextBoxes have a 'value' property that retrieves the written text in that element. So you should do the following, ASSUMING you are using inputs in HTML: `length1 = document.getElementById("length1").value;`

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the values of the elements ussualy are Strings, so, you should then convert these Strings to Numbers before comparing them.

Comment: I see now. I have a few examples to look at for help and it was for multiplication, not addition. Totally forgot to do that conversion/value set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("length c");
```

The line above only returns the DOM element, you should get the value of it, cast it to integer and compare those values.

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("length c").value)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, attempting to answer an obviously duplicated question or one that doesn't meet SO standards usually results in downvoting. You should attempt to only answer questions where it's unlikely been asked/answered before and where effort has been made in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

length1 length2 and length3 are not integers, they are elements. comparison is either undefined or not what you're expecting.

You need to add `.value` to get their numerical value (given they are a valid input element)

```js
var length1 = document.getElementById("length a").value;
var length2 = document.getElementById("length b").value;
var length3 = document.getElementById("length c").value;
```

Comment: `.value` won't contain the numerical value...

Comment: @lee-taylor You're wrong, this is javascript not TypeScript.

Comment: It will return a string. You will then have to convert to an integer.